# Exclude Private Pods from Acknowledgements.plist

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, podfile

The CocoaPods `Podfile` for my iOS app uses a `post_install` hook to copy the generated `Acknowledgements.plist` file to my application's Settings bundle. However, the file contains (proprietary) private pods that I'd like to exclude.

### Question

I'm aware that I can manually modify the items in the copied `Acknowledgements.plist` file. How would I exclude specific private pods from the file programmatically?

### Code

This is the `post_install` hook that copies `Acknowledgements.plist` to the Settings bundle.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  raw_acknowledgements = File.read('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-Acknowledgements.plist')
  formatted_acknowledgements = raw_acknowledgements.gsub(/(?<!>)(?<!\n)\n( *)(?![ \*])(?![ -])(?!\n)(?!<)/, ' ')
  # How do I exclude specific pods before the file is copied?
  File.open('MyApp/Supporting Files/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', "w") { |file| file.puts formatted_acknowledgements }
end
```

### Update

I added an answer below that works for now. However, I'm open to accepting another answer that does not involve modifying licenses or using a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

It's possible to exclude private pods from the generated `Acknowledgements.plist` by removing both the LICENSE file and the `license` object from the `Podspec`. In the private `podspec.json` file, the `license` object looks similar to this:

```json
"license": { "type": "Proprietary", "file": "LICENSE" }
```

This solution will not work without also removing the LICENSE file.

#### Option 2

An alternative solution that does not require modifying private pod licenses is to use the CocoaPods Acknowledgements plugin. After installing the `cocoapods-acknowledgements` gem, add something like this to your `Podfile`:

```rb
plugin 'cocoapods-acknowledgements',
  :settings_bundle => true,
  :targets => ['MyApp'],
  :exclude => ['PrivatePodA', 'PrivatePodB']
```

Note that the `post_install` hook from the question is not needed with this solution.